# EXIF data not available when upload image using camera in iPhone

Tags: javascript, exif-js

I created component for image upload and it's display image details including the GPS location. I read the GPS details using EXIF data. Its work fine when we upload images using computer. Its also work fine if we use "Photo Library" or "Choose Files" options in iPhone. The problem is GPS details not display in EXIF data while uploading images using iPhone camera "Take photo" option. I already changed my camera format settings to  "Most Compatible".

I'm using exif-js library for read EXIF data.

[image]